# Por que no pasa mi variable a la vista blade?

Tags: laravel

Por que no pasa la variable usuario a la vista del componente?

este es mi componente:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;


class PerfilComponent extends Component
{
    public $id, $nombre, $correo, $password;

    public function mount(){
      $id = Auth::id();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $usuario = User::where('id','=',$id)->get();
        return view('livewire.Perfiles.perfil-component',compact('usuario'));
    }


}
```

Coloque esto en el route/web

```
Route::view('/perfil', 'livewire/Perfiles/perfil-component');
```

y esta es la vista de mi componente:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div>
  @foreach($usuario as $usu)
    {{$usu->name}}
  @endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

cuando me voy a localhot:8000/perfil me aparece el siguiente error:

ErrorException
Undefined variable: usuario (View: /../resources/views/livewire/Perfiles/perfil-component.blade.php)

he revisado proyectos anteriores con livewire y no me pasaba esto. qué podrá ser?

Comment: fijate que ya intente eso y como cosa rara siempre me da el error, es como que si se saltara el dd()

Answer (score 0):

Al hacer esto `Route::view()` la ruta se va **directamente** a la vista, sin pasar por el componente y método `render()` por eso no encuentra la variable `$usuario`.

Si quieres que funcione tal y como está ahora, en tu route/web, debes adjuntar también la variable usuario, algo así: `Route::view(...,['usuario' => 'data'])`

Intenta poniendo la ruta de la siguiente manera: `Route::livewire()` o `Route::get(..., PerfilComponent::class)`.

Comment: al hacerlo de esta forma: Route::get('/pass', PerfilComponent::class); me da el error de "Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\PerfilComponent]." tengo otras ejemplos donde no uso rutas y funciona todo bien trabajando directamente del home. como sería la forma mas facil de usarlo?

Comment: Debes agregar la ruta completa de tu componente `Route::get('/pass', App\Http\Livewire\PerfilComponent::class)`, lo pones directamente allí o lo importas usando `use  App\Http\Livewire\classname` en la parte superior

Comment: ya había intentado colocarlo y cuando lo hago aparece este error: Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Livewire\PerfilComponent]

Comment: Qué versión de laravel y qué versión de livewire estás usando?

Comment: Laravel v7 y livewire 2.2

Comment: Intenta poner la ruta completa, pero poniendo un backslash al inicio (absolute path)`\App\Http\Livewire\PerfilComponent::class`, debido a que tu namespace está en Controllers

Comment: si hago esto: Route::get('/pass', '\App\Http\Livewire\PerfilComponent'); me da página Not found y si lo coloco sin las comillas me da siempre invalid route action

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115206/discussion-between-l-flor-and-mau-espana).